# Listbox Height calculation Converter

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, ivalueconverter

How can I calculate the Height of a listbox to fit the listbox items exacltly.
For example if my Listbox Height is streched and for this moment the height is 320 and a listbox item Height is 25. Then I will have 12 items and a piece of the 13th item. I dont want to display halve or a piece of an item. It should display only the 12 items and not the 13th item at all.Then when resizing the window it should always calculate the number of items that will fit in full as you resize. I want to achieve this by using a Converter that will calculate the Height of the listbox to fit all items exactly.

Comment: A `WrapPanel` will do the job if you bind the child elements `Width` to the WrapPanel `Actualwidth`.

Comment: What happens if you remove the Height property and only set a MinHeight? Doesnt the listbox grow in height as items are added?